# Возможно ли сделать более одного сайта доступными в LAN в OpenServer?

Tags: openserver

Есть ли у Open Server'a возможность крутить в LAN 2 или более сайтов?

Comment: Чем же "Windows HTTP-сервер" не угодил? :)

Comment: Какую задачу вы решаете? Вам, возможно, нужен другой подход.

Comment: Крутиться Help-desk на php+mySQL  
Ещё надо запустить и документооборот на php+mySQL

Comment: @I_CaR, извините, что в корне переделал весь Ваш вопрос, но в Вашей редакции слишком много лирических отступлений и слишком мало вопроса.

Comment: Вам не нужен опенсервер (равно как и мягкий знак в "крутится"). Опенсервер - это средство для разработки, которое включается и выключается на чьем-то компьютере, а реальные приложения должны крутиться на сервере, который не выключается вообще и не зависит от этого человека. Несмотря на то, что апач там ровно тот же самый, что и на линуксе (пусть сборка другая), вы все равно рано или поздно упретесь в то, что это всё должно висеть отдельно.

Comment: @ReinRaus значит будем писать как в газетах. - "Ищу дев. с чу. без п.в. с пмж"!

Comment: @Etki Эм-м-м... вы давно в ИТ?

Comment: Пять лет скоро.

Answer (score 1):

Да, такая возможность есть. Ознакомьтесь с соответствующим разделом [документации](http://open-server.ru/docs/#vneshnij-dostup).

Comment: так ip же у сервера один.

Comment: На одном ip может быть размещено сколько угодно сайтов.

Comment: Путём переписывания хост-файлов у клиентов?

Answer (score 0):

Может, как и любой популярный веб-сервер, называется это [Алиасы](https://ospanel.io/docs/#domeny-i-aliasy)

Comment: Спасибо. Это что-то более-менее подходящее.
Правда та реализация проектов уже похоронена.